# Singapore - enter and exit on different passports?

Tags: air-travel, passports, singapore

I would like to visit a friend in Singapore during my travels and an hoping to book a transfer there.

My US passport allows me entry to Singapore, but I want to use a different passport to enter my destination country in SEA. Will I encounter issues entering and leaving Singapore on different passports?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: TL;DR: Switch passports between countries, not within them.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to use the same passport on entry and exit, but that doesn't mean you can't use another passport on entry at your next destination...

Show both passports to the airline staff on check in in Singapore, and use your US passport at (automated) passport control when exiting Singapore.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense